# How to Calculate the number of days where bar value is above the avg line in line and stacked column chart Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a DAX formula to calculate the number of days `[Task_Progress_Date]` where the bar value `[Task Progress Count]` is above the line `[Task Progress Count Avg (Daily Future)]` and (based on the graph it show to be 22 days) but I am not able to get the value at all. It shows 169, which is way off.

```
Overload Future Days Ind =
IF([Task Progress Count] > [Task Progress Count Avg (Daily Future)], 1,0)

Task Overload Days (Future) =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Task Progress Calendar'[Task_Progress_Date] ),
    FILTER ( 'Task Progress Calendar', [Overload Future Days Ind] = 1 )
)
```

22 Days